# PyParallel not working in OpenBSD

Tags: python, parallel-port, openbsd

I am trying to run PyParallel on OpenBSD to control some relays via the parallel port. I downloaded it, then installed it with the command `sudo python setup.py install` and it seemed to work. But now I am getting an error when I try to import it.

```
import parallel

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    import parallel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parallel/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from parallelioctl import *     #IOCTLs
ImportError: No module named parallelioctl
```

I have searched the web for info on the file parallelioctl, but to no avail.

If anyone has ideas, I would appreciate them!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that it's possible to use pyParallel on OpenBSD.

According to the docs it supports Linux and Windows, and when you look at the Linux section it talks about certain kernel modules that need to be loaded and unloaded and specific device drivers that are unlikely to be compatible with anything OpenBSD has.

http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyparallel.html